# Javascript / jQuery "Dangle" animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I would like to create an animation in jQuery or preferable pure javascript that makes a div "dangle". I have attached an animated gif that shows the animation. I don't know how recreate this, if it is something I can use an existing jquery easing / animation for or javascript + css animation or how. I also thought about canvas, but that would limit my ability to manipulate content etc.

[image: Dangeling animation]

**RESULT:**

Thanks to @peirix for helping me out with the CSS animation. Here is the result I was hoping to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/zeg61pb7/7/

**CSS**

```
#box {
   width:30px;
   height:30px;
   position:absolute;
   top:100px;
   left:100px; 
   text-indent: 90px;
   background-color:#aaaaaa;
    transform-origin: top center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    -webkit-animation: dangle 2s infinite;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 50%;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

#box:after {
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    background: #aaaaaa;
    top: -4px;
    left: 12px;
    content: '';
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.dims {
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: #aaaaaa;
    top: 125px;
    left: 110px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: movee 2s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dangle {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    5% { -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); }
    10% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-28deg); }
    15% { -webkit-transform: rotate(26deg); }
    20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg); }
    25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(22deg); }
    30% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg); }
    35% { -webkit-transform: rotate(18deg); }
    40% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-16deg); }
    45% { -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    55% { -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-6deg); }
    65% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes movee {
    9% { left: 110px; }
    10% { left: 120px; }
    15% { left: 100px; }
    20% { left: 114px; }
    25% { left: 106px; }
    30% { left: 113px; }
    35% { left: 107px; }
    40% { left: 111px; }
    45% { left: 109px; }
    50% { left: 110px; }
}
```

Comment: To the person down voting: I don't believe this is a useless question, neither do I believe I have shown no effort in possibilities myself. If you don't believe this is a suited community for these sorts of questions, could you advice me to a better place, please? Leaving downvote without explanation is unnecessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well. You don't really need javascript for that. All you need is some CSS love. I made a quick fiddle to show the basics. Just play around with the numbers a bit to get what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/zeg61pb7/3/

One note, though. Keyframes is still in need of `-prefix` for webkit browsers (chrome, safari, safari on ios, android etc), so you need to write it once with, and once without the prefix to hit all browsers. (Even IE10 and IE11 supports this)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try with css3.

Here is an interesting [demo](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) in Github.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeg61pb7/6/) with an example of how it can be done.
It depends on the [transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)-Plugin for jQuery.

```
var count = 0;
var deg = 45;
var minus = 5;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    $ $('#box').transition({ 
        rotate: deg + 'deg',
        transformOrigin: 'center top'
    }).transition({ 
        rotate: '-'+deg+'deg',
        transformOrigin: 'center top'
    });
        if(count === 5){
            clearInterval(interval);
            $('#box').transition({ rotate: '0deg' })
        }
    if(deg > 10){
        deg = deg-(minus+5);
     }
    count++;
}, 300);
```

A big plus is, that you can chain different transitions and transforms to your element.
But it`s an additional Plugin which must be loaded.

Comment: I think OP wants the object to dangle, but slowly come to a stop (more physics based). Your fiddle is a continuous transition.

Comment: @lhan so I updated my fiddle and my code. I added a counter to stop the Interval and now it stops the "dangling" slowly

Comment: That is better. I was doing some research as well looking into the jquery easing functionality, but didn't find anything that suits this scenario exactly. It seems to me more like a pendulum that slowly stops.

Comment: @lhan this got me to another idea. Now you can play around with the variables to find a smoth animation of "dangling". I think i won't get it more "physical"

Answer (score 0):

Indeed CSS3 can work some magic here, but you would still need Javascript to start and stop the animations, on hover or click events, for example.

I've made a small [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyfrgqgr/2/). Try and hover the red box. I've used `webkit`-prefixes, but you should be able to switch that easily with `moz` or `ms`.

The key differences to other suggestions here are

- use `animation-iteration-count: 1` to make it dangle once and then stop.
- use `$.on('<prefix>animationStop')` to remove the animation class. this hack is needed to restart the animation later on.